# NoMethodError: undefined method `symbolize_keys!' for Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, rake, rakefile

I'm trying to use `Hashie` outside of Rails. In my rakefile, I've included `require hashie/hash`, but I still get the `NoMethodError`. I've tried using `require hash`; no luck there either.

This is the line it fails on:

```
YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read('../prefs.yml')).result)['dev'].symbolize_keys!
```

When I `inspect` the Hash, it looks correct and takes this form: `{'key':'value'}`. I want the key to be a symbol, but I don't want to have to switch between Rails 3 and 4, so I installed `Hashie` and added it to my Rakefile, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Can anyone tell me why I might be getting this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`symbolize_keys!`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb#L34) method belongs to `activesupport`([github](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport) [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport/)) and you can't use this it without this gem.

In order to use it add it to your Gemfile(or via `bundle add activesupport`)
and explicitly require it in your code

```ruby
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/keys'
```

---

Or you can write use a polyfill like [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/bogdanRada/4286379)

https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport/